# Translating compact sets in locally compact groups

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I wonder, when $G$ is a locally compact group (fix a Haar measure) what can be said about the set
$$\{ g\in G\colon g^{-1}A\cap A \neq \emptyset \},$$
when $A$ is a compact subset of $G$.

Comment: Why do we need to fix a Haar measure? The rest of the question has nothing to do with the Haar measure...

Comment: unnecessery indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a\in g^{-1}A\cap A$ then $A\ni a=g^{-1}b$ for some $b\in A$, hence $g=ba^{-1}$. Conversely, if $a,b\in A$ and $ba^{-1}=g$ then $a\in g^{-1}A\cap A$. So
$$S=\{g:g^{-1}A\cap A\ne\emptyset\}=AA^{-1}.$$

You say you want to know "what can be said about" $S$. It's not clear from this exactly what question about $S$ you want an answer to, but it seems  likely that whatever can be said about $S$ follows from knowing that $S=AA^{-1}$. (In particular, for example, it follows that if $A$ is compact then $S$ is compact...)

Comment: @VanillaThunder Yes and no. No: I have no idea what you mean by $B$ in your comment. Yes: Continuity of the group operations shows first that $A^{-1}$ is compact, hence $A\times A^{-1}$ is compact and hence so is $AA^{-1}$. (That's probably what  you meant II suppose...)